# How to Cherry-Pick only Code-Changes (without Metadata e.g. Date, Message)?

Tags: git, visual-studio, github, bitbucket

I have a repository with a finished project and want to load the commits (step by step) into a new repository, with new messages and the current date. Any tips? Using VS2019 and bitbucket.

Comment: `git cherry-pick --no-commit` ? (That's not possible with Visual Studio)

Comment: `git cherry-pick --edit`? `git diff` + `git apply`? `git diff` + `patch`?